# How can I separate these divs in the javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this div scrolling script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.tab-box').each(function () {
    var top = 0;
    var $tabbox = $(this);
    var height = $tabbox.height();

    $(this).find('.tab').each(function () {
        var shift = top;

        $(this).click(function () {
            $tabbox.find('.items').animate({
                marginTop: shift + 'px'
            });
            $tabbox.find('.tab').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });

        top -= height;
    });

    $(this).find('.tab:eq(0)').addClass('active');
});

});
```

If I understand it correctly it gets every divs working only within the div "tab-box".
http://jsfiddle.net/9SfEH/5/

What I want to change is that I separate the "tabs" from the main tab-box div, but make them still controll the "items".
http://jsfiddle.net/w65Dn/1/

I was trying for a simple solution buuut couldn't come up with one by myself.
Thanks everyone in advance :)

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/w65Dn/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in the original code, it was looking for the tab clickables using `$(this).find(".tab")`, but the `.tab`s were no longer inside of the `.tab-box`. So, if you just search globally, with `$(".tab")`, it works.

Note that you can no longer have more than one tab box, because it is searching globally for the `.tab`s. You could use something like javaCity's solution (i.e. wrapping everything in another div) to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

On line 7, change the selector from this to .tabs

```
$(this).find('.tab') becomes $(.tabs).find('.tab')
```

as seen here: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/w65Dn/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You were looking for `.tabs` inside the `tab-box` which does not exist. So how about creating a div outside of `.tab`s which also encloses `tab-box`?

http://jsfiddle.net/3D8we/

HTML:

```
<div class="enclosingDiv">
    <div class="tabs">
        <div class="tab">1</div>
        <div class="tab">2</div>
        <div class="tab">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-box">
        <div class="items">
            <div class="item" style="background: #cbe86b;"></div>
            <div class="item" style="background: #f2e9e1;"></div>
            <div class="item" style="background: #1c140d;"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tab-box').each(function () {
        var top = 0;
        var $tabbox = $(this);
        var height = $tabbox.height();

        $('.enclosingDiv').find('.tab').each(function () {
            var shift = top;

            $(this).click(function () {
                $tabbox.find('.items').animate({
                    marginTop: shift + 'px'
                });
                $tabbox.find('.tab').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });

            top -= height;
        });

        $(this).find('.tab:eq(0)').addClass('active');
    });

});
```